# Change maxlength based on name="..." Possible?

Tags: input, maxlength

I'll admit, I'm new to this world. Im working on my first site, which has a template file setup. In the template I have a code thats similar to

```
<input type="text" name="option[**]"/>
```

Where `Option[**]` is pulled from somewhere else, heres my issue;

Is there something I can do to limit the text input length based on the option number pulled? I did a

```
<input maxlength=10 type="text" name="option[**]"/>
```

and that worked to limit all my text input boxes there to 10, however I have say `Option[1]` and `option[2]`; I want 1 limited to 10 and 2 limited to 15. is this possible? remember, Im new to all this :)